# Add UITableViewController's view to another UIViewController, the "delegate" and "date source" are not called

Tags: ios, tableview

I had created a UITableViewController in IB, named MyTableViewController. The xcode generate MyTableViewController.m, MyTableViewController.h and MyTableViewController.xib which contains a tableview in them.

Then I added the generated table view to another view controller by following code,

```
MyTableViewController *myTableViewController = [[MyTableViewController alloc] init];
UITableView *myTableView = (UITableView *)myTableViewController.view;
myTableView.frame = CGRectMake(190, 190, 500, 160);
myTableView.delegate = myTableViewController;
myTableView.dataSource = myTableViewController;
```

As a result, delegate methods in MyTableViewController.m won't get called,
e.g. "numberOfSectionsInTableView", "numberOfRowsInSection", "cellForRowAtIndexPath".

Any suggestion on it? Thanks.

Comment: Have you written <UITableViewDelegate,UITableViewDataSource> in .h file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not loading the XIB file, so I suspect `myTableView` is nil.  Instead of this:

```
MyTableViewController *myTableViewController = [[MyTableViewController alloc] init];
```

Try this:

```
MyTableViewController *myTableViewController = [[MyTableViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"MyTableViewController" bundle:nil];
```

Also, you need to tell your view controller that it has a childViewController, and tell your tableViewController that it has a parent VC.  Put the following lines around your `addSubview`:

```
[self addChildViewController:myTableViewController];
[self.view addSubView:myTableView];
[myTableViewController didMoveToParentViewController:self];
```

Comment: So cool answer!   if I won't add the last 3 words that you mentioned, it still doesn't work. That's why? Besides I did in this way to maximum the reuse of the table view part. Any comments on that?

Comment: I don't quite understand your question regarding maximum reuse of the tableView.  But whenever you try to put a view controller's view as a subView of another view controller, you should use the above sequence: `addChildViewController`, `addSubview`, `didMoveToParentViewController`.